# Probability with Balls and Dice

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose a biased die is rolled with the probability P(X=x) = (7-x)/21 for x = 1,2,3,4,5,6 with the number rolled, x, corresponding to the number of balls drawn from the urn.

> a) Find the probability of drawing all green balls.
>
> b) Find the probability of rolling a 2 given that all the balls drawn were green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw all green balls, you need the number on the dice to be one of $1,2,3,4,5$.
Then, you need to count how many ways to choose that many green balls from the fifteen.
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Draw only green balls})
&= \sum_{x = 1}^5 P(X = x) P(\text{The $x$ balls drawn are all green}) \\
&= \sum_{x = 1}^5 \frac{7 - x}{21} \cdot \frac{5 \choose x}{15 \choose x} \\
&=
\frac{2}{7} \frac{5}{15} + 
\frac{5}{21} \frac{10}{105} + 
\frac{4}{21} \frac{10}{455} + 
\frac{3}{21} \frac{5}{1365} + 
\frac{2}{21} \frac{1}{3003} \\
&=
\frac{85}{693}
\end{align*}

Then looking at just one of the terms,
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Roll a 2 and all balls are green})
&= \frac{5}{21}\frac{10}{105} = \frac{10}{441}
\end{align*}

So the probability that $X = 2$ GIVEN that all the balls are green is
$$
\frac{10\,/\,441}{85\,/\,693} = \frac{22}{119}.
$$